# In a circle the angle at the center is double the angle at the circumference when the angles have the same circumference as base.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry

I have the following theorem : 
"In a circle the angle at the center is double the angle at the circumference when the angles have the same circumference as base."

(Figure is in the link)
http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/propIII20.html

English isn't my first language, so I just want to make sure that I understood something correctly. We prove the theorem by putting the two angles one on the other for the circumference. I was just wondering, can I assume that the angles do not need to be one on the other and they can have different portion of the circumference, as long as the circumference are of the same lenght ? (Will the proposition still work in this way?) I guess that Euclid did the proof by putting the angles one on the other for making the demonstration less wordy. (Less long to read)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could say the same as long as the circumferences are the same length (arc lengths are the same) .

You could prove this by using both the theorem you link to above and the theorem that congruent arcs have congruent central angles (or congruent central angles have congruent arcs).

Comment: Sorry if my question seems obvious (I'm new to the domain of proofs). But do I really need to prove the case where they aren't one on the other ? What we just proved doesn't assume this case  ?

Comment: @Astroman: The theorem that you linked to *does* assume that the arcs are on top of each other. I just point out that you can use one more fact to then easily prove the case where the arcs are not on top of each other. This means you don't need another long proof (similar to but distinct from the one you linked to).

Comment: Ok, my original question was more does euclid's proof prove both cases, when they are on top of each other and when they aren't. Anyway, thanks for the help!